# Do Russian citizens need a visa to leave the airport during a long layover in France?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, south-african-citizens, russian-citizens, schengen-visas

I have a long layover in France. Do Russian citizens need a visa to leave the airport for about 6 hours?  I also have South African passport.

Answer (score 2):

Both [Russians](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=ru&DE=fr&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX) and [South Africans](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=za&DE=fr&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX) need a visa to enter France. Doesn't matter if it's 3 months or one minute: if you cross the border, you cross the border, full stop, and thus require a visa.

In the application form for a Schengen short-stay visa, put in "transit" as the purpose of entry.